# Angular2 route change not destroying components correctly

Tags: sockets, angular, typescript, socket.io, angular2-routing

I have a communications module with component hierarchy like this -

```
CommsComponent > ChannelsComponent > [ChannelComponent, ChannelComponent, n]
```

**Comms component template:**

```
<div class="row m-t-md">
  <comms-channels></comms-channels>
</div>
```

**Channels component template:**

```
<template ngFor let-channel [ngForOf]="channelService.channels | async">
   <comms-channel [channel]=channel
     [hidden]="channel.name !== selectedChannel?.name">
   </comms-channel>
</template>
```

**Channel component template:**

```
<ul *ngFor="let message of messages">
   {{ message.text }}
</ul>
```

**Services:**
ChannelService - creates a new socket connection to '/channels' namespace:

```
subscribeToChannelEvents() {
    let listenEvents = [ 'channel:connect', 'channel:create', 'channel:list' ];
    this.socket = new SocketService(this.config.apiEndpoint);
    this.socket
      .connect(this.socketName, this.listenEvents)
      .subscribe((socketEvent: ISocketEvent) => {
        this.listen(socketEvent);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

MessageService - creates a new socket connection to '/messages/{{ channel }}' namespace, *for each channel*.

```
subscribeToMessages() {
      let listenEvents = [ 'message:sent', 'message:list' ];
      this.socket = new SocketService(this.url);
      this.socket
        .connect('messages/' + encodeURIComponent(this.channel.name), listenEvents)
        .subscribe((socketEvent: ISocketEvent) => { this.listen(socketEvent); },
          error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
```

**The problem** is that on route change (navigate away from comms URL and then back), the message socket connections are *recreated for each channel*. The existing socket connections are either not reused correctly **or** not properly destroyed when changing the route. On refresh(F5) all these connections are properly destroyed and the correct number of connections are made again.

**Analysis:**
I've logged the events and noticed a random destroy while re-creating the channel components on URL change back to comms. (Between 3 and 4).

```js
1. On page load:

[constructor] ChannelService
[constructor] SocketService create
SocketService Connected to 'channels'

[constructor] ChannelsComponent < CREATED 

[constructor] ChannelComponent - General
[constructor] ChannelComponent - Sales
[constructor] ChannelComponent - Orders

[constructor] MessageService -  General
[constructor] SocketService created for General
[constructor] MessageService -  Sales
[constructor] SocketService created for Sales
[constructor] MessageService -  Orders
[constructor] SocketService created for Orders

SocketService Connected to 'messages/General'
SocketService Connected to 'messages/Sales'
SocketService Connected to 'messages/Orders'

2. On url change away:

(ngOnDestroy) channel -  General
(ngOnDestroy) channel -  Sales
(ngOnDestroy) channel -  Orders
(ngOnDestroy) ChannelsComponent < DESTROYED
… load new components

3. On url change back to communications:

… destroy previous components
[constructor] ChannelsComponent < CREATED AGAIN

[constructor] ChannelComponent - General
[constructor] ChannelComponent - Sales
[constructor] ChannelComponent - Orders

[constructor] MessageService -  General
[constructor] SocketService created for General
[constructor] MessageService -  Sales
[constructor] SocketService created for Sales
[constructor] MessageService -  Orders
[constructor] SocketService created for Orders

WHAT IS DESTROYING THIS?
(ngOnDestroy) channel -  General
(ngOnDestroy) channel -  Sales
(ngOnDestroy) channel -  Orders
(ngOnDestroy)  > no ChannelsComponent?  < NOT DESTROYED

Created again...

[constructor] ChannelComponent - General
[constructor] ChannelComponent - Sales
[constructor] ChannelComponent - Orders

[constructor] MessageService -  General
[constructor] SocketService created for General #
[constructor] MessageService -  Sales
[constructor] SocketService created for Sales #
[constructor] MessageService -  Orders 
[constructor] SocketService created for Orders #

SocketService Connected to 'messages/General'
SocketService Connected to 'messages/Sales'
SocketService Connected to 'messages/Orders'
SocketService Connected to 'messages/General' #
SocketService Connected to 'messages/Sales'     #
SocketService Connected to 'messages/Orders’ #

4. On url change away:

REPEAT from no 2.
```

Comment: What's your question? If your question is "what causes this behavior in my code?", don't you think being able to see the code might help answering the question?

Comment: My question is why are the ChannelComponents being destroyed right after constructing them in point 3, and then created again straight after? This module is part of a large solution so I tried to show the pieces of relevance.